# Doing CFA on a known theoretical model, but having problems with convergent and discriminant validity

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor, amos, validity

I did a survey based on the [UTAUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_theory_of_acceptance_and_use_of_technology) model / theory with standard questions used. The N was 150. I am trying to validate the model for my survey with structural equation modeling (via the AMOS software). But I have heard that before testing the model fit, "it is absolutely necessary to establish convergent and discriminant validity, as well as reliability, when doing a CFA" (confirmatory factor analysis).

Doing CFA, I found out that factor loadings are OK (using AMOS, loadings > 0,7).
I did CR for reliability testing, everything OK - over 0,7. But (not like other published papers) I have problems with convergent and discriminant validity (note results below).

[image]

Is there some way to deal with this or do I have to restate the questions and repeat the survey? (I think doing exploratory factor analysis is not logical if so many others have proven the theory works, so does that mean something must be wrong with my data?)

Comment: What do you mean by convergent and discriminant validity? Do you mean how the model or parts of the model correlate with other models or constructs?

Comment: @Behacad, to put it simply, convergent validity is how well each variable loads onto its respective factor, whereas discriminant validity is how poorly each variable loads onto other factors other than the factor it loads most highly on. For example, if we had a questionairre with 4 items (Do you feel blue today? Do you ever have thoughts of suicide? Are you depressed? Are you happier than you have been your entire life?), we would expect the first 3 items to have convergent validity with one another and discriminant validity with the "happy" item, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doomed. But you may llok at Zaid and Bartea, 2011 to calculate discriminant validity after Segars, 1997. It involves calculating fit coefficients with two constructs at a time twice having the first one correlated and the second uncorrelated between constructs. Comparing the fit measures between these two methods if they are significantly different as per CMIN criteria for 1 degree of freedom, then discriminant validity is said to exist.

Comment: Could you please give the references for your citations?